# OneDrive on MacOS: file not available despite "always keep on this device" activated

Tags: macos, sync, onedrive

[Onedrive-finder screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEKVN.png)

I have marked the "03_education" folder as "Always keep on this device" (this can be seen by the white tick on grey background). However, it seems that the files are not actually in that location. 2 reasons why I think this:

1. The little cloud-with-downward-arrow icon next to the tick that on hovering gives me the tooltip "Not Downloaded".
2. When I double-click "03_education.Rproj" nothing happens, and after a while finder gives me an error message "The file doesn't exist".

I guess if I wait long enough, the files will be available in that location again, but that is exactly what I wanted to avoid when I chose "Always keep on this device".

Information from [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/save-disk-space-with-onedrive-files-on-demand-for-mac-529f6d53-e572-4922-a585-e7a318c135f0) suggests that despite the cloud-with-downward-arrow icon the file is available on my Mac, but possibly in a different location. This doesn't help me, unfortunately, as when I try to open a file it takes a long time until it's available.

I would appreciate any advice on what is happening exactly and how I could fix it. Thanks!